# Unable to get AccessToken with Azure B2C, IdToken present but no scope permissions

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I'm following [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/resources/samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi/) tutorial to setup a client / server using Azure B2C.

I *think* I've done everything correctly but I'm experiencing a couple of issues.

1. `AccessToken` is null, but `IdToken` is populated

When I try to access protected resources, the following code is executed after I sign in at `https://login.microsoftonline.com`. The following line fails because AccessToken is `null`:

```
request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
```

TaskWebApp.Controllers.TaskController.cs (Client App):

```cs
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    try
    {
        // Retrieve the token with the specified scopes
        var scope = new string[] { Startup.ReadTasksScope };
        string signedInUserID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
        TokenCache userTokenCache = new MSALSessionCache(signedInUserID, this.HttpContext).GetMsalCacheInstance();
        ConfidentialClientApplication cca = new ConfidentialClientApplication(Startup.ClientId, Startup.Authority, Startup.RedirectUri, new ClientCredential(Startup.ClientSecret), userTokenCache, null);

        var user = cca.Users.FirstOrDefault();
        if (user == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("The User is NULL.  Please clear your cookies and try again.  Specifically delete cookies for 'login.microsoftonline.com'.  See this GitHub issue for more details: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi/issues/9");
        }

        AuthenticationResult result = await cca.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(scope, user, Startup.Authority, false);

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, apiEndpoint);

        // Add token to the Authorization header and make the request
        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken); //AccessToken null - crash
        //request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.IdToken); //This does work however
    }
    ...
}
```

Contents of `result AquireTokenSilentAsync`:

[image]

2. `IdToken` doesn't contain `Scope` permissions

If I use `IdToken` in place of `AccessToken` - I get a little further but I'm hitting a new stumbling block. It fails here:

TaskService.Controllers.TasksController.cs (WebAPI):

```cs
public const string scopeElement = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/scope";

private void HasRequiredScopes(String permission)
{
    if (!ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(scopeElement).Value.Contains(permission)) //Crashes here as token doesn't contain scopeElement
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage
        {
            StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized,
            ReasonPhrase = $"The Scope claim does not contain the {permission} permission."
        });
    }
}
```

And here is a screenshot of my `ClaimsPrincipal.Current`:

[image]

Any advice is appreciated.

**Edit**

Signin URL:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/te/turtlecorptesting.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_email/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=03ef2bd...&redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a44316%2f&response_mode=form_post&response_type=code+id_token&scope=openid+profile+offline_access+https%3a%2f%2fturtlecorptesting.onmicrosoft.com%2fread+https%3a%2f%2fturtlecorptesting.onmicrosoft.com%2fwrite&state=OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties%3daDQntAuD0Vh=...&nonce=63655.....YWRmMWEwZDc.....
```

Comment: looks similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43970669/failed-to-get-accesstoken-via-authorization-code-using-msal-1-1-0-preview-in-asp

Comment: Can you paste the redirect URL that is generated for the authorize endpoint?

Comment: Hey @ChrisPadgett - updated question.

Comment: Have you handled [the `AuthorizationCodeReceived` notification](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi/blob/cf011352babed2685c9c324e308a2b8775640c2b/TaskWebApp/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs#L74)?

Comment: Yep - my Startup.Auth is the exact same as what you've linked...

Answer (score 0):

1. Under Azure AD B2C go to your application

[image]

2. Under API access click add, select your API and its scope(s)

[image]

You should now get AccessToken in your response.